# Is it possible to get around PHP session checks?

Tags: php

I've got a user login field that sets the session after they're validated on the login page:

```
 $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
 $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
```

And on this PHP page I only want logged in users to access I have at the top:

```
<?php session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['id']) && !isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header('Location: http://--back to home page--');
    exit(); <-- Added thanks to comments
}
?>
```

Is this enough to keep user who have not logged in off the page?
It's redirecting me back to the home page when I'm not logged in, but could people get around it?

Edit: I've added the `exit();` now.

Comment: Session hijacking.... but the fact that you're not exiting after the `header()` line means that the rest of the code in the script is ___always___ being executed

Comment: To me it sort of sounds like enough, although realize that `header()` adds an HTTP-response-header, which can be ignored by the browser. Basically, don't rely EVERYTHING on the user not being able to get past a `Location` field, because they can. A tip can be adding `exit` after the header-call.

Comment: Okie, i've added the exit (completely forgot to do that), is there anything I can do to stop session hijacking?

Comment: One method (XSS) can be stopped by disallowing the input of malicious HTML-tags (such as `<script>`) entered from input fields to be stored without further ado, in case you have any of those

Comment: suppose if you wanted more, you could match $_SESSION and a secret to database (properly santized of course) values for the user. You could also turn the logic around and only display content if this is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users can bypass the HTTP `Location` header. Add a [`die();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) (Which is equivalent to [`exit();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)) right after to prevent any other content from being sent to the browser.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['id']) && !isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header('Location: http://--back to home page--');
    die();
}
```

---

Other than that, note that a user can change the `PHPSESSID` cookie. If they find the id of an active session with the variables in question set, they will gain access to the page.

Comment: Would it be better to randomly choose some like massive 15 digit number for the session ID? - At the moment it's just the ID from the database (I will go find a php security book tomorrow!)

Comment: Are you setting the session id with `session_id($id);`? If not, PHP generates its own 32 character (by default) sequence.